# inserting in a sorted way and getting index in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a project that involves a chat system

I would like to insert chatMessages to an array in the correct place (by `id` ) and get the index of it.

How could I achieve that?

---

One thing to mention, the message ids are normally **Integers**, but if you send a message then temporarily it gets a `pendingId` (for example *"aBe3BwqKBe"*), and the id gets the same value.

After the message is successfully sent, It receives the correct `id` from the database, and sets it correctly.

---

So for example I have an array with those messages:

```
id: "1"
id: "2"
id: "aBre4Jvwrk" (pending)
id: "5"
id: "6"
```

If I receive a message with `id` **4**, I would like to insert it before the `id` **5**, and I would like to get the index of it. How could I achieve that in such a complex situation?

**Code:**

```
class ChatRoom: NSObject {
    var id : String!
    var pendingId : String?
    var title : String!
    var messages : [ChatMessage]
    var users : [Int]

    init(id : String, title: String, messages: [ChatMessage], users: [Int]){
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.messages = messages
        self.users = users

        super.init()
    }

    func insertMessageAtCorrectPlace(message : ChatMessage) -> Int {
        // Insert message 
        messages.append(message)
    }
}

class ChatMessage: NSObject {
    var id : String!
    var pendingId : String?
    var userId: Int!
    var message: String!
    var sentTime: Int!

    init(id : String, userId: Int, message: String, sentTime : Int){
        self.id = id
        self.userId = userId
        self.message = message
        self.sentTime = sentTime

        super.init()
    }
}
```

Comment: When sorting the array, how will you decide that `aBre4Jvwrk` goes after `2` and before `5`?

Comment: *the message ids are normally Integers*. No, they aren't. The code clearly reveals that the ids are `String`. And please **never ever** declare properties as implicit unwrapped optional if they are initialized non-optional. Remove all exclamation marks